# Redux saga put push is not changing location

Tags: react-router-v4, redux-saga

I try to change location when the user is successful login but seems like not working. I'm using  "connected-react-router": "^6.2.2" and this is code:

```
...
yield put(authenticationActions.getAuthenticationRequestSuccess({
      token,
      authProfile,
      companyProfile,
      userProfile,
    }));
    yield put(push('/com'));
...
```

I have redux chrome plugin and last action is :

```
{
  type: '@@router/CALL_HISTORY_METHOD',
  payload: {
    method: 'push',
    args: [
      '/com'
    ]
  }
}
```

But the path is not changing. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Have you already read this fresh [GitHub issue](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router/issues/230) similar to yours?